# Synchronize animation in SVG elements using CSS

Tags: css, svg

I am trying to create a simple blinking SVG element using the following CSS:

```
.led-red-blink {
    animation-name: grey-red;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    stroke-width: 1;
    stroke: #808080;
}
.led-red-blink:hover {
    animation-name: grey-red;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    stroke-width: 1;
    stroke: #efefef;
}

@keyframes grey-red {
    0% { fill: #808080; }
    50% { fill: #EE5544; }
    100% { fill: #808080; }
}
.led-green-blink {
    /* just like led-red-blink */
}
```

and the UI elements (width, height, x, y removed for clarity):

```
<rect class="led-red-blink" id="led-h1"></rect>
<rect class="led-green" id="led-ok"></rect>
```

The animation works fine on its own, but if I assign the led-red-blink class to another rect object, they blink out of sync.
The rects' class can be changed at any time.

How would it be possible to sync the animation of all rect objects to happen simultaneously? I.e. whenever a rect's class is changed, the start time for each rect animation is identical instead of whenever the change was made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group the svg elements into a g tag, assign it a class and use that class to apply the animation.

like this -> [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5eefbau7/)

```
<svg height="100" width="300">
    <g class="circles">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
    <circle cx="200" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
    </g>
</svg>

g.circles {
    -webkit-animation: move 3s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes move {
    0%{
        opacity:1;
    }
    100%{
        opacity:0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. The only issue I have is that with this, the object appears and disappears as opposed to toggling between two specific appearances. I've solved this by adding a background image first, but this requires two objects. Is there a better solution?

Comment: You can use jQuery to toggle your animation class on the g element as opposed to my previous solution. It's probably an even better solution. I will prepare a jsfiddle when I reach my pc and get back to you :)

Comment: Check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rj1cfhq8/4/) 
Note that we need to use attr when attributing the class to svg elements. The setTimeout part of code "resets" your animation so you can run it multiple times.